# use a .gs file in a web page in App Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

I'm using a script to extract data from google search console in a sheet.
I built a sidebar to chose on which website the user want to analyse his data.

For that i have a function that can list all sites link to the google account, but i have an error when i try to execute this function in my html file.
I use withSuccessHandler(function)  method which sets a callback function to run if the server-side function returns successfully. (i have a OAuth2.0.gs file where is my getService function.
The error is "service.hasAccess is not a function at listAccountSites" where listAccountSites is my function. Here's an extract of my html file:

```
<script src="OAuth2.0.gs"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(function() {
  var liste = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(listAccountSites)
      .getService();
   console.log(liste);
});

function listAccountSites(service){

  if (service.hasAccess()) {

    var apiURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/webmasters/v3/sites";

    var headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()
    };

    var options = {
      "headers": headers,
      "method" : "GET",
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);

    var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(json)
    console.log('if')
    var URLs = []
    for (var i in json.siteEntry) {
      URLs.push([json.siteEntry[i].siteUrl, json.siteEntry[i].permissionLevel]); 
    }
    /*
    newdoc.getRange(1,1).setValue('Sites');
    newdoc.getRange(1,3).setValue('URL du site à analyser');
    newdoc.getRange(2,1,URLs.length,1).setValues(URLs);
    */
    console.log(URLs);
  } else {
    console.log('else')
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
    Browser.msgBox('Open the following URL and re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl);
  }

      return URLs;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: Does the error go away if you use`if (service.hasAccess)`?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution.
Jquery is useless here, you just have to use google.script.run.yourfunction() to run your gs. function on your html sidebar.